# Stratified sampling to generate random numbers (eg. for Monte-Carlo applications)

Tags: sampling, monte-carlo, stratification, importance-sampling

I am using a Monte-Carlo method to compute a value of interest $y$ from some input parameters $x_{i}$, that I use to draw statistical sets from simple distribution laws.
In my case, for a single Monte-Carlo iteration $j$, I can obtain $y_j$ by sampling $N$ values for each one of my $M$ input parameters, which all follow a specific distribution (in my case, $x_{i} \sim \chi^2_i$), such that:

$$
y_j = f (x_{1}^1, \dots , x_{1}^N, x_{2}^1, \dots , x_{2}^N, \dots , x_{M}^1, \dots , x_{M}^N) 
$$

On the basis of some bibliography, and in order to improve the convergence rate for $y$, I tried to use stratified sampling to obtain a better exploration of the distributions followed by my input parameters. Basically, for each $x_i$, instead of sampling $N$ values from a $\chi_i^2$ law, I split in $N$ strata the $\chi_i^2$ cumulative distribution. Then, I use the inverse cumulative method to obtain $(x_{i}^1, \dots , x_{i}^N)$ values from $(u^1, \dots , u^N)$ values sampled from an uniform distribution. For $N = 5$:

[image]

Once this is achieved, I shuffle the obtained set of  $(x_{i}^1, \dots , x_{i}^N)$ values. All the $M$ obtained sets are shuffled independently.

However, such a stratification method seems to lead to a systemic bias. I have been looking for a reason which could explain it, as I was expecting the results to be roughly the same than for the non-stratified case, at least asymptotically. 
I have been investigating some hypothesis, which lead me to two questions:

1. What is the optimal number of strata to consider ? Maybe, taking $N$ strata is a kind of over-stratification. In the context of stratified sampling for survey applications, some interesting work has been achieved in order to optimize the stratification boundaries choice, usually to obtain the best estimation of a population characteristic (ie. with fewer costs, which might mean few strata and/or few samples). For example, next work from M.G Khan and al. ("Determining the optimum strata boundary points using dynamic programming", https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/en/pub/12-001-x/2008002/article/10761-eng.pdf?st=FdsrqVKZ) details a method implemented in R to determine the best strata and sample sizes for a population following some analytical distribution (eg. normal, chi-square...). However, an issue with this method is the fact it take into account the real finite size of the population from which a subsample is taken. The situation I consider is quite different, as I want to generate random numbers for Monte-Carlo applications, ie. my population is "infinite" theoretically.
2. Is this method of stratification valid only for some form of the $f$ function (eg. linear, like a mean) ? Instinctively, I was assuming that stratification would lead to "better" random numbers, and that the form of $f$ would not impact this hypothesis, but my biased results make me doubtful now.

If anyone could have any hint, I'd be grateful.

Comment: The problem is that you impose to the $N$ entries of $(x_1^1,\ldots,x^N_1)$ to all belong to different strata. This vector has obviously a different distribution than an iid vector  $(x_1^1,\ldots,x^N_1)$ even when $f$ is exchangeable in the $N$ first entries.

Comment: Sure, but isn't it the principle of stratified sampling ? I am trying to apply variance reduction to my problem, and stratified sampling is often mentionned as a basic way to do it.

Comment: I think you are applying stratified sampling to the wrong object: $(x_2,x_2,....,x_M)$ should be stratified.

Comment: Indeed, that sounds more reasonable to obtain a result on y... (and kicks out my naïve interpretation of "better exploration of the input cumulative function", whatever the objective...) Thanks, I'll try that !
It seems to me that the first part of my question holds though: how many strata shall I consider, and is there an optimal way to perform a stratified Monte-Carlo sampling from a chi-square distribution (or whatever well-known analytical distribution) ?

Comment: One point per strata sounds like the ultimate choice, provided they all get the same weight. It then becomes a sort of QMC.

Comment: @Xi'an, Thanks! I'm glad you mentionned QMC by the way. Does that mean that I cannot use my obtained $(y_j)$ anymore with this method to estimate the probability distribution followed by $y$ ? Even if I can work out something with the mean of course.